# Elasticsearch Bulk Index no Error

Tags: json, elasticsearch, cmd

I am running the code below on the cmd line (Windows) to bulk index about 3 million docs, but nothing happens. I run it and one second later it is done with no output and the index is not even created.

```
 curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -XPOST "localhost:9200/test1/_doc/_bulk" --data-binary "@huge_JSON"
```

I run the same line on a few lines of this document and it works fine.

Also running it on a file with 300k documents works.

Why is it not working and not giving an error?

Edit: 
For whatever reason I now get the error:

```
curl: option --data-binary: out of memory
```

Comment: How big is your file in MB?

Comment: The file is 850MB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split up the file (Use cygwin etc. if on Windows):

```
split -l 100000 huge_JSON
```

Run this line to index each of the split files:

```
for %%i in (*) do curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -XPOST "localhost:9200/test1/_doc/_bulk?pretty&refresh" --data-binary  @%%i
```

OR

Just use logstash